# Bootstrap.4 - Building Carousel Using Slick

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, slick.js

I am trying to build a responsive carousel as present in [Mecca](https://www.mecca.com.au/coronavirus.html) website. I am using Bootstrap 4 and using slick plugin to build the carousel.

The look and feel i am trying to achieve is the something like this picture
[image: Tile 1 in Carousel]

As i am using boostrap 4, to build this tile, I have written the following code and codepen link is given below

```
 [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bzaidi/pen/MWamJvZ)
```

I am facing the following problems

1. This carousel is not responsive. I need to change font-size using media queries on almost every resolution. If I see Mecca website, their carousel is perfectly responsive.
2. When i float the image left, the rightContent div seems to be taking all the width of parent div which is 290px? Why is that?
3. Is my approach correct?
4. How can I achieve responsiveness on all resolutions?

Can you someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: @NishargShah I have added complete snippet of code. if you need the image, please let me know thanks.

Comment: give me your code in `codepen` with all images and I think your responsive problem is solved by me in another question

Comment: @NishargShah i have shared the link to the code pen. I am still figuring out how to create a codepen. Simply preview custom-carousel.html and you should be able to see. I am editing my question to target specific problems.

Comment: I answered you in your different question and that solve your responsiveness problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436967/show-different-number-of-slides-on-different-breakpoints-using-slick-carousel

Comment: @NishargShah that is a very different question to this problem. Here I am facing responsiveness issue with the whole component itself. The text, link, and image all get displaced.